# convert xml data stored in a table to individual name/value pairs stored as records in a different table sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I'm sorry, I didn't fully explain what I'm looking for. Here is whatI am using:

The table contains xml in the following format"

```
<row>
  <POLICYNUMBER>IFH6000258-04</POLICYNUMBER>
  <POLICY_NO>CFH6000258</POLICY_NO>
  <POLICY_MOD>03</POLICY_MOD>
 </row>

declare @mystuff xml;
set @mystuff = (select top 1 * from TMP_APP for xml path)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[FredTest]
(       
  [xmlstuff]
)
VALUES
(
  @mystuff
 )


    DECLARE @hldit table (ID int not null,xmldata xml)
  * set @hldit = (select xmlstuff from FredTest)
    Select   entr.value('local-name(.)', 'VARCHAR(50)') as nme,
             entr.value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(50)') dta
    From @hldit
    Cross apply
             XmlData.nodes('/root/row/*') as xt(entr)
```

I get an error on the set(see *). I can't seem to populate the table.

I want to insert the output into a table with 2 columns,'name' and 'value' and have a separate record for each pair.

The output should look like;

```
         Name                  Value
record 1 Policynumber          IFH6000258-04
record 2 Policy_no             CFH6000258
record 3 Policy_mod.           03
```

I feel like I am close. Everything runs but I can't populate the @hldit table. I hope this explains my problem.
Thanks

I am new to XML. I have to extract records, store them in an xml data field in a different table, then extract the xml data and store the name/value pairs in another table. I'm good up to creating the xml data. What I can't figure out is how to take the raw xml from the table, create a table with the name/value pairs stored as individual records. I have looked and tried everything out there but still now luck. I'm hoping the final rows in the new table would look like:

```
name      value
--------------------------
firstname Fred
lastname  jones
address   123 here street
```

instead of like this:

```
firstname="fred" lastname="jones address="123 here street"
```

I'll even take it in xml PATH format instead of RAW.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL database name and version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I know what you are after.
Please try the following conceptual example.

It will work in MS SQL Server 2005 onwards.

**SQL #1, attributes based**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<root>
    <r firstname="fred" lastname="jones" address="123 here street"/>    
    <r firstname="Laura" lastname="Bush" address="257 somewhere street"/>
</root>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(30)') AS [Column]
    , c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Value]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/root/r/@*') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+----------------------+
|  Column   |        Value         |
+-----------+----------------------+
| firstname | fred                 |
| lastname  | jones                |
| address   | 123 here street      |
| firstname | Laura                |
| lastname  | Bush                 |
| address   | 257 somewhere street |
+-----------+----------------------+
```

**SQL #2, elements based**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @destination TABLE (ID INT, pos INT, [Name] VARCHAR(30), [Value] VARCHAR(100));

DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmldata XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmldata) VALUES
(N'<row>
  <POLICYNUMBER>IFH6000258-04</POLICYNUMBER>
  <POLICY_NO>CFH6000258</POLICY_NO>
  <POLICY_MOD>03</POLICY_MOD>
 </row>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

INSERT INTO @destination (ID, pos, [Name],[Value])
SELECT ID
    , c.value('let $n := . return count(../*[. << $n])+1', 'INT') AS pos
    , c.value('local-name(.)','VARCHAR(30)') AS [Name]
    , c.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS [Value]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY xmldata.nodes('/row/*') AS t(c);

-- test
SELECT * FROM @destination;
```

**Output**

```
+----+-----+--------------+---------------+
| ID | pos |     Name     |     Value     |
+----+-----+--------------+---------------+
|  1 |   1 | POLICYNUMBER | IFH6000258-04 |
|  1 |   2 | POLICY_NO    | CFH6000258    |
|  1 |   3 | POLICY_MOD   | 03            |
+----+-----+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: your answer is good but I need to get the data from a table with an xml column, please see the additional information I added

Comment: Yitzhak. I was able to get it working as you suggested. I now need to pull it from a table and thank you for all the help.

Comment: @FastFreddy, I updated the answer with the version #2. Check it out.

Comment: Yitzhak. We're getting close :).

Comment: Yitzhak. Once i changed from raw to path, everything works. Thank you for your help. Is there anyplace that explains what you did. I've been working in sql for 10 years and your code blew me away.

Comment: @FastFreddy, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as **Answer**. Also, please connect with me on Linkedin.